# How to create a custom html page template in wordpress theme and how to link that page with other css/php file?

Tags: wordpress

```
            <?php
              /*
                 Template Name: isbn design
              */

                   get_header();

                    <!DOCTYPE html>
                    <html>

                   <head>
                   <title>Sell your book</title>
                   <link rel-"stylesheet" type="text/css" href="isbndesign.php">
                   </head>

                   <body>
                    <form method="post">
                   <input type="text" class="textbox" placeholder="Search">
                   <input title="Search" value="" type="submit" class="button">
                    </form>
                    </body>
                    </html>

                    <?php

                    get_footer();
```

// This code i have written for a search box ... i have no idea about how to make a page template in word press so i have written this foolish code here.. In title tag i have link a php file naming "isbndesign.php". In this file i have written css code which refer to designing of the search form.
But when i am selecting this template in a page it is showing nothing.
So please tell me how to make this custom template and design it in wordpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this this a how to create **custom template**. you can enqueue CSS in **function file**.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Standard Template
Template Post Type: page
*/
get_header();
?>

 // Your code

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: but how will i link that css file with this template?

Comment: @Ashu just enqueue CSS in function file its automatic consider or you can put in template also like this <link rel-"stylesheet" type="text/css" href="isbndesign.php">

Comment: ohk thank you sir.... if you don't mine can i have your email so that if i will face any issue i can mail u easily

Comment: Sure dipak3.dds@gmail.com